# Interposing functions calls from static library to system framework

Tags: c++, ios, c, static-libraries

I have a situation in which I need to interpose function calls made by a third-party static library to an iOS system framework (a shared library).  Chances of cost-effective or timely maintenance support from the vendor of the static library are slim to non-existent.

In effect changing the calling sequence from:

```
+-------------+      +-------------+       +---------------------+
| Application | ---> | libVendor.a | ----> | FrameworkA (.dylib) |
+-------------+      +-------------+       +---------------------+
```

to:

```
+-------------+      +-------------+       +------------+       +---------------------+
| Application | ---> | libVendor.a | ----> | Interposer | ----> | FrameworkA (.dylib) |
+-------------+      +-------------+       +------------+       +---------------------+
```

The orthodox solutions to this problem is either to persuade the run-time linker to load a different library in place of `FrameworkA` or loading libraries with `dlopen()`.  Neither of these are options on iOS.

One solution that does work is using `sed` to rename symbols in the the symbol table of `libVendor.a`.

Suppose I want to interpose calls `FrameworkA_Foo()` in `FrameworkA` made by functions in `libVendor.a`:

```
sed s/FrameworkA_Foo/InterposeA_Foo/g < libVendor.a > libInterposedVendor.a
```

And then interpose it with:

```
void InterposeA_Foo()
{
    // do some stuff here 
    // ....
    // then (maybe) forward 

    FrameworkA_Foo();
}
```

This works just so long as the length of the symbol names remains the same.

Whilst this approach works, it lacks elegance and feels fairly hacky.  Do better solutions exist?

Other approaches considered:

- Changing link order in order to get the interposing function to link to `libVendor.a` rather than the framework: Apple's linkers (unlike those on most UNIX platforms) recursively resolve symbols in libraries, and the order they are presented on the command line makes little difference)
- Linker scripts: Not supported by `lld`
- mach-o object-file editing tools: Found nothing that worked

[For clarity, this is C (rather than Objective-c) API and the toolchain is `clang`/LLVM. Using an Apple-supplied GCC is not an option due deprecation and lack of C++11 support]

Comment: What about [hooking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooking#API.2FFunction_Hooking.2FInterception_Using_JMP_Instruction)?

Comment: @Dani Sadly not an option on several counts: Firstly, use of  `dlopen()` - required to inject the shared library is prohibited. Secondly: So is self-modifying code (at least as far as the AppStore guidelines are concerned) and thirdly, `libVendor.a` is by no means the only caller of `FrameworkA_Foo()`

Comment: I don't think the AppStore will accept any app that diverts library calls in any way.

Comment: @marko `dlopen()` works perfectly fine on iOS.

Comment: There is a suggestion that `dlopen()` is treated as a private API and therefore not permissible in App store apps.   Now, naturally the run-time dynamic linker is *capable* of both dynamically loading libraries and modifying at least some pages of the libraries its loads in order to link them in the first place, so the sandbox clearly allows all of this.  But the question of whether an app would get rejected for it is ambiguous.